# Controlling a text object through python. Hooking it to an internal variable

Tags: python, properties, text-object

Okay so I'm using a text object eventually odd like to make it into a health counter. My code is sloppy though and needs refining.

Here is what I got.

```
import bge
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
T = scene.objects['Text']
z = cont.sensors['z']

if z.positive:
    T ['x'] += 1

if T ['x']  == 0:
    T.text = 'failure'

if T ['x']  == 1:
    T.text = 'success'      

if T ['x']  == 3:
    T.text = T['x']
```

The last line didn't work, the money says that it returns without exception set. This is just a test to find something that sort of works. But ideally I'd like the texts to simply display a variable as it changed. Z is a keyboard sensor and x is a property linked to the text. Can someone tell me how I can just get the text to display the integer property x?

Also being able to reference the lines in a text file for text would be great but if that's to much to ask then please just help me with the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to execute your code, I get the error:

```
KX_GameObject, key "x" does not exist
```

Replace all your *T['x']* with another objects property such as:

```
T.localPosition.x
```

If this isn't the property you want, you can search the objects fields with:

```
print(dir(T))
```

You have to parse/cast the int to a string with the python str() method.
The last line compiles fine as:

```
if T.localPosition.x  == 3:
    T.text = str(T.localPosition.x)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing that last str() command. Works perfectly now that it recognizes the integer as a string

Comment: Nice to hear. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.